# SAP Central Management Console Parameters not aligned

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have been designing Crystal Reports, and publishing them to the SAP Central Management Console, for the past couple of years; but I have never come across this really strange issue before!

The report in question has 7 Parameters:

- 1 is a static String Parameter,
- 1 is a static Date Range Parameter
- 3 are static Number Parameters
- 1 is a static String Parameter with a pre-defined list of values
- 1 is a multi-level dynamic String Parameter

All of these parameters work fine when running reports from the Designer application itself, but as soon as it's published to the Central Management Console it all messes up:

- If you choose the first Parameter, you get the first parameter input screen.
- If you choose the second Parameter, you get the first parameter input screen.
- If you choose the third Parameter, you get the second parameter input screen.
- If you choose the fourth Parameter, you get the third parameter input screen.
- etc.

This means that there is no way of selecting the 7th Parameter as it shows you the 6th parameter input screen.

This behavior started when I added two of the static Number Parameters. Before this everything worked fine, and I cannot find online documentation/help which would allude to a Parameter limit in CMC.

- Crystal Reports Designer Version: Crystal Reports 2008, Version 12.3.0.601
- Central Management Console Version: SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI, Product 12.1.0

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating I realised that the problem was Central Management Console does not interact well with multi-level parameters.

I changed the multi-level parameter to two separate parameters, and everything is working.